# angularjs issue with (error catch is not a function)

Tags: angularjs

Hi I need some minor direction. I can pull the data in the viewCtrl but every time i go to add a new contact, the issue I get is $http(..)then(..)catch is not a function at oBJECT.$scope.addContact I have no idea what is causing this?
Its also not allowing me to "POST" but I am able to "GET". Can anyone see whats wrong with what i am doing?

```js
       var app = angular.module('app', []);

        app.controller('viewCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            var url = "https://";
            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: url,
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                }
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.contacts = data.d.results;
                console.log($scope.contacts);
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});





        });


        app.controller('addItemsController', function($scope, $http) {
         
                var url = "https://";

                $scope.addContact = function() {
                    return $http({
                        headers: {
                            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                        },
                        method: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        data: {
                            'Lastname': $scope.Lastname,
                            'Firstname': $scope.Firstname
                        }
                    })
                        .then(saveContact)
                        .catch(function(message) {
                            console.log("addContact() error: " + message);
                        });

                    function saveContact(data, status, headers, config) {
                        alert("Item Added Successfully");
                        return data.data.d;
                    }
                }
                //console.log("an item has been added!");
            });

        app.controller('editItemsController', function($scope) {

            $scope.editItem = function() {
                console.log("an item can now be edited!");

            }

        });


        app.controller('deleteItemsController', function($scope) {
            $scope.deleteItem = function() {

                console.log("item has been deleted");
            }

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="app">

<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="viewCtrl">

        <div ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
            {{contact.ID}}: {{contact.Lastname}}, {{contact.Firstname}}
            <button>Edit</button>
            <button>Delete</button>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3>Add Contacts</h3>
    <div ng-controller="addItemsController">
        <div class="Table">
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="Cell">
                    First Name :
                </div>
                <div class="Cell">
                    <input type="text" id="Firstname" ng-model="Firstname" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="Cell">
                    Last Name :
                </div>
                <div class="Cell">
                    <input type="text" id="Lastname" ng-model="Lastname" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="Cell">

                </div>
                <div class="Cell">
                    <input type="button" id="btnAddContact" value="Add Contact" ng-click="addContact()" />
                    <input type="button" id="btnAddContact2" value="Add Contact" ng-click="addItem()" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />

    <h3>Edit Contacts</h3>
    <div ng-controller="editItemsController">
        <div class="Table">
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="Cell">
                    ID :
                </div>
                <div class="Cell">
                    <input type="text" id="itemId" ng-model="itemId" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="Cell">
                    First Name :
                </div>
                <div class="Cell">
                    <input type="text" id="firstName" ng-model="firstName" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="Cell">
                    Last Name :
                </div>
                <div class="Cell">
                    <input type="text" id="lastName" ng-model="lastName" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="Cell">

                </div>
                <div class="Cell">
                    <input type="button" id="btnEditContact" value="Edit Contact" ng-click="editItem()" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />

    <h3>Delete Contacts</h3>
    <div ng-controller="deleteItemsController">
        <div class="Table">
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="Cell">
                    ID :
                </div>
                <div class="Cell">
                    <input type="text" id="itemId" ng-model="itemId" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="Cell">

                </div>
                <div class="Cell">
                    <input type="button" id="btnDelContact" value="Delete Contact" ng-click="deleteItem()" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>






</body>


</html>
```

Comment: What **exactly** is the full error message?

Comment: angular.min.js:63 TypeError: $http(...).then(...).catch is not a function
    at Object.$scope.addContact

Answer (score 0):

I see some mismatch between function on 
**onviewCtrl**

> $http(...).success(...).error(...)

while on **addItemsController**

> $http(...).then(...).catch(...)

use which code you are available on

Comment: Both styles are available in AngularJS 1.2.0

Comment: what do you mean by styles?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/1yEUxORsew2O74T0RjXV?p=preview
I use this plunker , and adjust angular version. you can try it